# Is "marker box" of an list-item generated inside of the "principal box" or next to it?

Tags: css, w3c

Reading the [CSS specification section 9.2 Controlling box generation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#box-gen) it says:

> Certain values of the 'display' property cause an element of the
>   source document to generate a principal box that contains descendant
>   boxes and generated content and is also the box involved in any
>   positioning scheme. Some elements may generate additional boxes in
>   addition to the principal box: 'list-item' elements. **These additional
>   boxes are placed with respect to the principal box**.

So what exactly this "*with respect to* the principal box" mean? Is it "inside of principal box" (eg. parent-child relation) or is it "next to principal box" (eg. siblings relation)?

In other words, is list-item bullet (marker box) inside of list-item principal box? If so, does it mean that "marker box" is floated to the left in the principal box block formatting context?

Comment: try to ping the same user already answering your questions, he's probably the *only* one who can give you an accurate answer (there is also this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock but he's not around for a while).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property [list-style-position](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#x45) determines whether the marker box is next to the principal box or inside it.

The values are `outside` and `inside` respectively. The default is `outside`.